# java EE injection in superclass

Tags: java, dependency-injection

I am trying to inject a bean in a super class, like this:

```
public class DsmCrudDaoProcuder 
{

    @Produces
    public static DsmCrudDao produceDao(InjectionPoint injectionPoint) {
        return ((CRUDSessionBase)injectionPoint.getBean()).createCrudDao();
    }
}


public abstract class CRUDSessionBase{

    @Resource public SessionContext context;

    protected static Log log = LogFactory.getLog(CRUDSessionBase.class.getName());
    protected static Log logger = LogFactory.getLog(CRUDSessionBase.class.getName());


    @Inject @New
    DsmCrudDao dao;

    /**
     * Get the concrete DAO
     * 
     * @return
     */
    protected abstract DsmCrudDao createCrudDao();



....
}
```

this fails on deployment:

> WELD-001409 Ambiguous dependencies for type [DsmCrudDao] with
>   qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject
>   com.windriver.dsm.ejb.CRUDSessionBase.dao]. Possible dependencies
>   [[Managed Bean [class
>   com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.dao.TECodeCoverageDao] with qualifiers
>   [@Any @Default], Managed Bean [class
>   com.windriver.dsm.enterprise.dao.BinaryGroupDao] with qualifiers [@Any
>   @Default], Managed Bean [class
>   com.windriver.dsm.labmanagement.dao.TeBlockCoverageDao] with
>   qualifiers [@Any @Default], Managed Bean [class
>   com.windriver.dsm.enterprise.dao.DeviceSupportedServiceDao] with
>   qualifiers [@Any @Default], ....

all of the beans in the list of the error are derived classes of `DsmCrudDao`.

Is there a way to make this work?